# Login with Facebook in Laravel 4

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, laravel, laravel-4, facebook-php-sdk

All I'm trying to do is have the user connect with facebook, grab his information (email, name, profile_pic) and register him automatically on my site.

the problem is when I visit /user/login/fb/ I get redirected to the fb application to grant permission and then it redirects me to

> http://local.serv/user/login/fb/callback?code=AQB7Uf7pcZSY89WYUKofY8bOgBY1qCcWA5p6_G-9MVdczN60C0TNOgFIi9LBRwquagZ6VbC6_kjD9-D0ZevKHyNGw88LuRJcuqdq2RbwCKNlC02_4eMtiNAWxX76XHm1CzU0F7nSVQ4KxENoDPFpKIs1oV-wQTkO7YuuGznL9UuzfK-hqTtZAIRBvQ_N_yh03LsdgaZ9-f6z5yc5FGnJ3sJyrC-3DGrjkSzhPpJHHk5tr7LorzqW9TNcaFpB9eE51wdsEHOa5oNEWycwzXjY-7Me1Uod3KVBGpb8tzeYVHArphMc2n45IF1pfAWMZZZ51Dw&state=f25e8641df013970542b7463b8899ccf#=

and give me this error

```
Facebook \ FacebookSDKException (700) 
You must provide or set a default application id.
```

Here are my routes

```
Route::get('user/login/fb', function() {

    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('', '');
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('user/login/fb/callback');
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
    return "<a href='$loginUrl'>facebook</a>";
});

Route::get('user/login/fb/callback', function() {
    // A FacebookResponse is returned from an executed FacebookRequest
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('user/login/fb/callback');
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');

    try {
        $response = $request->execute();
        $me = $response->getGraphObject();
    } catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }

    print_r($me);//->getProperty("id"));

    $user = new Giftee;
        $user->name    = $me->getProperty('first_name') . ' ' . $me->getProperty('last_name');
        $user->email    = $me->getProperty('email');
        $user->photo    = 'http://graph.facebook.com' . $me->getProperty('id') . '/picture?type=large';

        $user->save();

});
```

PS: if you have a clear tutorial with views and everything on how to integrate fb login with laravel please do share, I've been looking for days, the material is so limited.

Comment: You just posted your Facebook API credentials. Revoke them immediately and avoid making such mistakes in the future.

Comment: It's a test app, it's ok.

Comment: Test app or not, you don't want some malicious person doing bad (possibly illegal) stuff on your behalf.

Answer (score 2):

Your Facebook API credentials aren't set when you request the `user/login/fb/callback`, either add the `FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(...)` at the beginning of that route as well or use another library that allows you to set these in a global configuration file.

Your route should look like this :

```
Route::get('user/login/fb/callback', function() {
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(); // your API credentials

    // here goes the rest of your code
};
```